# Tkinter crashes when I start sniffing with scapy

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, scapy

So i'm trying to write a program where when you press "Start sniffing" it begins sniffing packets and prints it to the console, and when you press "Stop sniffing" it stops sniffing. Heres the code I wrote:

```
from tkinter import *
from scapy.all import *
from scapy.arch.windows.compa import * """Adds stop_filter to sniff because 
its not in scapy-python3"""
root = Tk()
Switch = False
def stopbutton():
   global Switch
   Switch = True
def stopsniffing(x):
    global Switch
    return Switch    
def action(packet):
   try:
      print ("%s went to %s"%(packet[IP].src, packet[IP].dst))
   except:
     pass
 def startsniffing():
    sniff(filter="host 192.168.0.48", prn=action, stop_filter=stopsniffing)
 button = Button(text="Start sniffing", command=startsniffing).pack()
 button2 = Button(text="Stop sniffing", command=stopbutton).pack()
 root.mainloop()
```

My issue is that when I press Start sniffing it begins to start sniffing, but everything else becomes unresponsive.

Comment: when you run long-running code then mainloop can'trun - it cant: gets key/mouse events from system, sends events to widgets, redraws widgets - so it looks like it freezes. you have to use tread to run sniffing code.

Comment: btw: don't use `except:pass`  because you will no see that you have error. At least display message ie. `except Exception as e: print(e)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sniff()` is long-running function so program can't return to `mainloop()` which gets key/mouse events from system, sends events to widgets, redraws widgets - so it looks like it freezes. You have to use `threading` to run `sniff()`.

```
import tkinter as tk
from scapy.all import *
from scapy.arch.windows.compa import *
"""Adds stop_filter to sniff because its not in scapy-python3"""
import threading

# --- functions ---

def sniffing():
    print('DEBUG: before sniff')
    #sniff(filter="host 192.168.0.48", prn=action, stop_filter=stop_sniffing)
    sniff(prn=action, stop_filter=stop_sniffing)
    print('DEBUG: after sniff')

def action(packet):
    try:
        print("%s went to %s" % (packet[IP].src, packet[IP].dst))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

def stop_sniffing(x):
    global switch
    return switch

# ---

def start_button():
    global switch
    global thread

    if (thread is None) or (not thread.is_alive()):
        switch = False
        thread = threading.Thread(target=sniffing)
        thread.start()
    else:
        print('DEBUG: already running')

def stop_button():
    global switch

    print('DEBUG: stoping')

    switch = True

# --- main ---

thread = None 
switch = False

root = tk.Tk()

tk.Button(root, text="Start sniffing", command=start_button).pack()
tk.Button(root, text="Stop sniffing", command=stop_button).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

---

**BTW:** if you do `var = Widget(...).pack()` then you assign `None` to `var` because `pack()/grid()/place()` returns `None`. If you don't need `var` then you can skip it

```
Widget(...).pack()
```

If you need `var` then you have to do it in two lines

```
var = Widget(...)
var.pack()
```